# Pattern type is incompatible with expected type?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, http4s

I am trying to create a post endpoint for a particular route but am getting the error message

> Pattern type is incompatible with expected type found ContextRequest[F,A], required: Request[F]

```scala
    case _ @ POST -> Root / "batch-notify" as _ =>
      handler.handle("create.notifications.batchNotify") {
        for {
          _ <- log.info("Running batch notification job") *> Sync[F].pure(())
          r <- batchingService.createNotifications.flatMap(_ => Ok())
        } yield r
      }.fireAndForget.flatMap(_ => Accepted())
```

I'm quite new to Scala and have tried fixing it but getting nowhere, would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to ask in the **discord** channel: https://discord.gg/NPqPSsKJ

Comment: What library are you using? Http4s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_ @ POST -> Root / "batch-notify" as _
```

aka

```
POST -> Root / "batch-notify" as _
```

aka

```
POST -> Root / "batch-notify" as user
```

is an `AuthedRequest` used for `AuthedRoutes`

https://http4s.org/v1/docs/auth.html

If you put it into a pattern matching where `Request` is expected for `HttpRoutes` (i.e. without authentication)

https://http4s.org/v1/docs/service.html

then you'll have a compile error

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : org.http4s.AuthedRequest[F,A]
    (which expands to)  org.http4s.ContextRequest[F,A]
 required: org.http4s.Request[F]
```

You can find example how to combine `AuthedRoutes` with `HttpRoutes` at https://http4s.org/v1/docs/auth.html#composing-authenticated-routes

```
val spanishRoutes: AuthedRoutes[User, IO] =
    AuthedRoutes.of {
        case GET -> Root / "hola" as user => Ok(s"Hola, ${user.name}")
    }

val frenchRoutes: HttpRoutes[IO] =
    HttpRoutes.of {
        case GET -> Root / "bonjour" => Ok(s"Bonjour")
    }

val serviceSpanish: HttpRoutes[IO] =
  middleware(spanishRoutes) <+> frenchRoutes
```